# Datatables with requirejs $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have problem when I load data-tables with requirejs.
**Following is my code**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "datatables" : "https://cdn.datatables.net/u/dt/jq-2.2.3,jszip-2.5.0,pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.12,b-1.2.1,b-colvis-1.2.1,b-flash-1.2.1,b-html5-1.2.1,b-print-1.2.1,fc-3.2.2,fh-3.1.2,r-2.1.0,sc-1.4.2,se-1.2.0/datatables.min",
    }
});


requirejs( ["datatables"], function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
        ]
    });
});
```

I have generated datatables.min.js from the following link:
https://www.datatables.net/download/

Already included the jquery and other extensions, but I got this error:

> $(...).DataTable is not a function

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you use  your code inside ready function ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery ready function, for example :

```
requirejs( ["datatables"], function() {
   $(function(){ // ready function 
     $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf'
        ]
     });
   });
});
```